# Microsoft IIS Url Rewrite 2.0 - rewrite url with x number of folders

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up a url rewrite rule using Microsoft IIS URL Rewrite 2.0, I'm running IIS7 and .NET 4.

I want to match any number of a specific pattern, for example:

```
www.test.com/test1/
www.test.com/test1/test2/
www.test.com/test1/test2/test3/
www.test.com/test1/test2/test3/test4/ etc...
```

and [respectively] rewrite the results as

```
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1&q=test2
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1&q=test2&q=test3
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1&q=test2&q=test3&q=test4 etc...
```

or

```
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1,test2
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1,test2,test3
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1,test2,test3,test4
```

This is a fairly straight forward thing to do when using the standard c# regex engine (I have considered creating a custom HttpModule to handle this and iterating over a Match collection), however I wanted to know if it was possible to do with the IIS url rewrite component as I'm using this quite happily for other parts of the site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just match and pass in

```
www.test.com/page.aspx?q=test1/test2/test3/test4
```

Then it would be up to `page.aspx` to parse it how it needs it? That way your configuration won't have to change when it really is application logic.

Comment: That's not a half bad idea, however this would conflict with an existing rewrite rule and force me to implement a handler/module to rewrite the requests based on another logical condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .net 4.0, what not use Routing?

http://everymanprogrammer.com/index.php/asp-net-4-0-routing-a-simple-tutorial-that-works/